# Is epoll still more efficient than blocking listen for HTTP 1.0?

Tags: c, sockets, http, epoll

HTTP 1.0 uses one connection per request and the server should close the connection after every request. That being said, I'm trying to compare two alternatives:

1) the usual blocking call to listen(), followed by accept(), recv() and close().

2) non blocking listen(), followed by accept() and epoll_wait(), recv() and close().

Epoll is usually regarded as the best alternative, but in a scenario where every request uses a new connection, epoll_wait wouldn't have to be watching for old file descriptors, making it look just like alternative #1, always waiting for a totally new file descriptor.

Strictly speaking about HTTP 1.0, is my assumption correct or have I missed something?

Comment: Consider if the client loses a connection due to outage your server is waiting for the timeout on that socket....

Comment: Even if you have one connection per request, how do you plan to handle multiple simultaneous requests?

Comment: The listen/accept/recv/close is not acceptable for any real-world server TCP use

Comment: By the way, the `listen` call will *never* block, it's the `accept` call that could block. The `listen` call only tells the system that the socket is a passive listening socket, nothing more.

Comment: I would handle simultaneous requests the same way as epoll, synchronously. Also if a timeout occurs even epoll will suffer because recv won't return. I still don't see a real advantage

Answer (score 0):

> HTTP 1.0 uses one connection per request and the server should close the connection after every request

That's only the default. With added `Connection: keep-alive` it supports multiple requests per connections too. In HTTP/1.1 this default is switched, i.e. one need to set `Connection: close` to get the default HTTP/1.0 behavior.

> That being said, I'm trying to compare two alternatives: ... blocking ... non-blocking

Both with HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 the client will usually do multiple connections to the server. The reason is that even with HTTP keep-alive (default in HTTP/1.1) the requests cannot be send in parallel on the same TCP connection but it has to be one request after the other and the responses come back in the same order the requests where send. Thus the only way to parallelize requests is to have multiple TCP connections open. And these are best handled either with non-blocking sockets or with threads or with multiple processes.

Only HTTP/2 supports multiple requests in parallel inside the same TCP connection, i.e. allows interleaving requests and responses and the responses can also be in different order of the requests. But even in this case the server usually needs to handle multiple TCP connections in parallel since there might be multiple clients at the same time.

Comment: My question was more about the benefit of using epoll for requests that don't reuse connections. Using epoll I won't be handling requests in "parallel" since I'll be using the same thread and I'll receive notifications for every new connection, just like the blocking accept(). So is epoll any good for Connection: close requests?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães: epoll is only relevant if you need to handle multiple TCP connections __in parallel__.  If you handle each TCP connection in a separate thread anyway then epoll ist of no use, no matter if you have only one request per connection or multiple. As I said, these multiple requests arrive in sequence and need to be answered in sequence anyway.